# iOS: Play short sounds in the background every 2 minutes

Tags: ios, audio, background, avaudioplayer

I have got a cycle timer app which plays short sounds at the end and start of each round (round is 2/3 mins, rest is 30/60 secs). All that works fine while in the foreground, but works only for some minutes in the background.
I have added background mode, but it doesn't help.
So how can i make it work? :)
Should i use AVAudioPlayer or AudioServicesPlaySystemSound?
UPD: here is an app makes what I want: https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/boxing-itimer/id506058665?mt=8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself, thanks everybody tryed to help me ;) To play the sound in the background more then once you have to use AVAudioPlayer add audio as a supported backgroundmode and add this method to - (void)viewDidLoad

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```